Convert Altium PcbDoc file between binary and ASCII without Altium
As Altium PCB file format support, we can save PcbDoc as binary or ASCII.
https://www.altium.com/documentation/altium-designer/pcb-dlg-confirmfileformatformfile-format-pcb-ad?version=20.2
Is there any toolkit or method that can convert PcbDoc between binary and ASCII without Altium?
Or any automation way to transfer binary to ASCII?
Any suggestion is welcome, thanks.

This may work for you using KiCad.
https://www.kicad.org/
Open the KiCad PCB editor, do File -> Import -> Non-KiCad Board File

Then save the file with a new name.  The result is a text based PCB doc like so:
    (kicad_pcb
        (version 20240108)
        (generator "pcbnew")
        (generator_version "8.0")
        (general
            (thickness 1.6)
            (legacy_teardrops no)
        )
        (paper "A4")
        (layers
            (0 "F.Cu" signal "TopLayer")
            (31 "B.Cu" signal "BottomLayer")
            (32 "B.Adhes" user "B.Adhesive")
            (33 "F.Adhes" user "F.Adhesive")
            (34 "B.Paste" user "BottomPaste")
            (35 "F.Paste" user "TopPaste")
            (36 "B.SilkS" user "BottomOverlay")
            (37 "F.SilkS" user "TopOverlay")
            (38 "B.Mask" user "BottomSolder")
            (39 "F.Mask" user "TopSolder")
            (40 "Dwgs.User" user "Mechanical10")
            (41 "Cmts.User" user "User.Comments")
            (42 "Eco1.User" user "User.Eco1")
            (43 "Eco2.User" user "Mechanical11")
            (44 "Edge.Cuts" user)
            (45 "Margin" user)
            (46 "B.CrtYd" user "B.Courtyard")
            (47 "F.CrtYd" user "F.Courtyard")
            (48 "B.Fab" user "Mechanical13")
            (49 "F.Fab" user "Mechanical12")
            (50 "User.1" user "Mechanical1")
            (51 "User.2" user "Mechanical2")
            (52 "User.3" user "Mechanical3")
            (53 "User.4" user "Mechanical4")
            (54 "User.5" user "Mechanical5")
            (55 "User.6" user "Mechanical6")
            (56 "User.7" user "Mechanical7")
            (57 "User.8" user "Mechanical8")
            (58 "User.9" user "Mechanical9")
        )
    <snip>

and
    (footprint "DIODE0.4"
        (layer "F.Cu")
        (uuid "09b20157-098f-41e7-9ca4-f77458af267c")
        (at 157.13708 98.01861 90)
        (property "Reference" "D2"
            (at 12.065 -1.27 0)
            (unlocked yes)
            (layer "F.SilkS")
            (uuid "3697152b-2b46-42be-bfe4-ab663ce67603")
            (effects
                (font
                    (size 1.27 1.27)
                    (thickness 0.254)
                )
                (justify left bottom)
            )
        )
        (property "Value" "1N4148"
            (at -0.8255 -1.9304 90)
            (unlocked yes)
            (layer "F.SilkS")
            (hide yes)
            (uuid "6fa2dfdd-48c3-48a1-a6b0-c4c074ec20db")
            (effects
                (font
                    (size 1.27 1.27)
                    (thickness 0.2032)
                )
                (justify left bottom)
            )
        )
        (property "Footprint" ""
            (at 0 0 90)
            (unlocked yes)
            (layer "F.Fab")
            (hide yes)
            (uuid "4cb3928b-4e74-4fea-8665-60b6910032fb")
            (effects
                (font
                    (size 1.27 1.27)
                )
            )
        )
        (property "Datasheet" ""
            (at 0 0 90)
            (unlocked yes)
            (layer "F.Fab")
            (hide yes)
            (uuid "3642e129-349e-43d9-9a91-cc25d0b054ee")
            (effects
                (font
                    (size 1.27 1.27)
                )
            )
        )
        (property "Description" ""
            (at 0 0 90)
            (unlocked yes)
            (layer "F.Fab")
            (hide yes)
            (uuid "4ecd92fe-6f28-418a-9ebd-afa7d083b0fb")
            (effects
                (font
                    (size 1.27 1.27)
                )
            )
        )
        (fp_line
            (start 8.128 -1.27)
            (end 8.128 1.27)
            (stroke
                (width 0.3048)
                (type solid)
            )
            (layer "F.SilkS")
            (uuid "4b461a8d-8466-485d-b150-74465495b9e5")
        )
    <snip>

What you really want to do with that, well, that's up to you.  I believe KiCad is scriptable.  However, I do not have any experience with doing so.
Good Luck!

Thanks for your advice. I'll check whether KiCad provide script or library to solve this problem, Thanks!

@NEET  If it was useful, please accept it as an 'answer'. electronics.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer
